# Choice Filter list based on User Group

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, custom-list, choice-field

I have two List web parts being filtered based on a connected Choice Filter web part. I would like the choices available in the filter web part to be the members of a SharePoint user group. For now, I have manually populated the filter choices - obviously that is not ideal.

Is there a way to provide a Choice Filter with a dynamic list of choices (SP or AD group) or another type of Filter Web Part that I could use to get this functionality?